# How to display a listview of custom fragments?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I am using Android 3.0. I want to display a listview containing fragments. Each fragment consists of an image, a description, and some other UI elements.

I'm looking for some sample code or pointers.

Comment: What exactly you mean by custom ListView as you can have image and description in other ListView too?

Answer (score 2):

Your Fragment should extend `ListFragment`. The ListFragment reference doc explains how to use custom `ListView` and row layouts.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

In the row layout (each row represents one list item), you can add an ImageView for displaying an image.

```
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
     android:textSize="16sp"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: it would be better if you explain what you are doing and paste some code/logs/stacktrace. "not working" is not constructive.

Comment: @Anirudh thanks for the clear response. Shouldn't the title here be display a custom listview of fragments. Or display custom fragments in a listview? It seems like the user's title is backwards.